Vue component not found from a personal library in another package due to path error
Library A
I've made a library which is a web client in vite/vue/vuetify. I create bundles with it and use it alone. Yet, I need to integrate it in another frontend. Here is the vite configuration to build this library.
/**
 * THIS IS A VITE CONFIGURATION FOR LIBRARY BUILD
 */

// Plugins
import Vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import Vuetify, { transformAssetUrls } from "vite-plugin-vuetify";
import ViteFonts from "unplugin-fonts/vite";
import dts from "vite-plugin-dts";

// Utilities
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "node:url";

import path from "path";

export default defineConfig({
  base: "/progqi/",
  plugins: [
    Vue({
      template: { transformAssetUrls },
    }),
    // https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader/tree/master/packages/vite-plugin#readme
    Vuetify({
      autoImport: true,
      styles: {
        configFile: "src/styles/settings.scss",
      },
    }),
    ViteFonts({
      google: {
        families: [
          {
            name: "Roboto",
            styles: "wght@100;300;400;500;700;900",
          },
        ],
      },
    }),
    dts(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
      "@assets": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/assets"),
      "@client": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/client"),
      "@components": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/components"),
      "@plugins": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/plugins"),
      "@stores": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/stores"),
      "@utils": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/utils"),
    },
  },
  build: {
    outDir: "dist/lib",
    lib: {
      entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/index.ts"),
      name: "progqi-frontend",
      fileName: (format) => `index.${format}.js`,
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      // make sure to externalize deps that shouldn't be bundled
      // into your library
      external: ["vue"],
      output: {
        // Provide global variables to use in the UMD build
        // for externalized deps
        globals: {
          vue: "Vue",
        },
      },
    },
  },
});

I took this config from this package I use and it generates me this kind of output:
dist/lib
├── App.vue.d.ts
├── client
├── components
├── favicon.ico
├── index.d.ts
├── index.es.js
├── index.umd.js
├── main.d.ts
├── plugins
├── stores
├── style.css
└── utils

The entrypoint is a vue plugin:
/**
 * index.ts
 *
 * Distribute vue application
 */

// Plugins
import { registerPlugins } from "@plugins/index";

import type { App as AppType } from "vue";

// Coponents
import App from "./App.vue";

export default {
  install(app: AppType, options: any[]) {
    // configure the app
    registerPlugins(app);
    app.component("MyClient", App);
  },
};

For the example, let's say the component tree looks like
App
  + Component A
  + Component B
  + Component C
    + Component C1

Running the builder creates the package content which is then distributed in a NPM registry.
Main frontend
I use this library as a npm package (npm install @my-scope/my-package) in the main front and include this plugin with vue.use(...).
import MyPlugin from "@my-scope/my-package";
export function registerPlugins(app) {
  loadFonts();
  app
    .use(vuetify)
    .use(MyPlugin)
    .use(router)
    .use(pinia)
}


I finally use my library App.vue component in the router as a global imported component.
const routes = [
  // catch all / 404 Not found routes
  { path: "/:pathMatch(.*)", component: () => import("@/components/global/NotFound.vue") },
  {
    path: "/plugin",
    component: "MyClient", // <-- same name as in plugin definition
  },
];

Yet, on dev server launch, it tries to reach all the library components, but it seems it searches it in the wrong adress, e.g. http://localhost:3000/src/components/ComponentA.vue, is if this belonged to the main front components. It finally raises a Not found.
Note that the App.vue component (the library main one) did not raise this error.
I can't understand. That's like if all library components were searched as a main package file.
Thanks for your help.

It's unclear what's going on, the question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . "in the main front and include this plugin with vue.use(...)." - how exactly, what's the import? " finally use my library App.vue component in the router" - how exactly? You are supposed to bundle the lib, so there's .js file that you import, not .vue, so no "src/components/ComponentA.vue" can appear in an app where you consume this lib

Ok, I'm really new to npm packaging. The problem was my package.json file whose main entry was not correct. I've though this was the source file, but it needs to be the bundled one.
Sorry for this (dump) question.
